# Rails f.select Saving only blank strings and not option values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

How do I get this Rails f.select to stop saving blank strings in the database? I'm getting 200's for both the API submission and the database submission, but the database and api are both sending blank strings.

View Code

```
<a href="#" class="button" id="new-suggestion-button" onclick="newSuggestionToggle(event)">New Suggestion</a>

<div id="new-suggestion-info">
  <h1>New Suggestion</h1>
  <%= form_for @suggestion, url: { action: "create" }, remote: true do |f| %>
    <div>  
      <%= f.select :name, options_for_select(@snacks.collect { |snack| snack["name"] if !snack["optional"] }), {}, { id: "snack-select", onchange: "otherSelected()" } %>
    </div>

    <br>
    <div id="other-snack-info">
      <h1>New Snack</h1>
      <div>
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
      </div>
      <div>
        <%= f.label :purchase_location %>
        <%= f.text_field :purchase_location %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <%= f.hidden_field :optional, value: false %>
      <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Controller Code

```
def index
    api_key = ENV["API_KEY"]
    @snacks = Unirest.get("https://address_is_correct" + api_key).body 
    @snacks << { "name" => "Other" }
    @suggestion = Suggestion.new
  end

  def create
    api_key = ENV["API_KEY"]
    Unirest.post("https://address_is_correct" + api_key,
      headers:{ "Accept" => "application/json" }, 
      parameters: { 
        name: params[:name], 
        optional: params[:optional], 
        purchase_location: params[:purchase_location],
        purchase_count: params[:purchase_count],
        last_purchase_date: params[:last_purchase_date]
      }
    ).body

    @suggestion = Suggestion.new(suggestion_params)

    if @suggestion.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js { render "create" }
      end
    end
  end

  private

    def suggestion_params
      params.require(:suggestion).permit(
        :name,
        :optional,
        :purchase_location,
        :purchase_count,
        :last_purchase_date
      )
    end
```

Parameters being passed through in the terminal look like this

```
[["name", ""], ["optional", false], ["purchase_location", ""], ["created_at", 2017-04-19 17:09:46 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-04-19 17:09:46 UTC]]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you may see through your output, the selected name does not reach the server side. This means that the issue is processed on the front end.

My guess would be that since you have 2 elements for name attribute (1 select, 1 input), your selected value is not submitted because input is placed after select element. Try removing input element or disabling it on option select.